# Use Field Calculator to change "Status" field in Annotations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, annotation

I am trying to turn off a lot of annotations at once by using Field Calculator to set status to *Unplaced*. Just typing `"Unplaced"` into the expression, I get this error:

> The calculated value is invalid for the row with ObjectID = 408. For example the calculated value may be too large for the field or you may be trying to add a string to a number field. This row will not be updated.

I understand that I'm trying to drop a string value into the field and it won't accept that. What data type/value should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Status values `"Placed"` and `"Unplaced"` are coded values in a Domain, representing actual values of `0` and `1` respectively. Try your calculation with `1` instead.

Comment: Works perfectly -- I feel silly for being baffled by that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's very frustrating that domain-coded fields can't be calculated using either the raw values or the codes. Hopefully on day. Would you mind marking the answer as correct? :)